# Fixing While Loops Python

Tags: python

6. We want to create a program that prompts the user to enter a number between 1 and 10. As long as the number is out of range the program reprompts the user for a valid number. Complete the following steps to write this code.

a.Write a line of code the prompts the user for number between 1 and 10.

```
number = float(input("Enter a number between 1 and 10: "))
```

b. Write a Boolean expression that tests the number the user entered by the code in step "a." to determine if it is not in range.

```
x = (number > 10 or number < 1)
```

c.Use the Boolean expression created in step b to write a while loopthat executes when the user input is out of range. The body of the loop should tell the user that they enteredan invalid number and prompt them for a valid number again.

```
while x == True:
    print("you printed an invalid number")
    number = float(input("please enter the number again, this time between 1 and 10"))
```

d.Write the code that prints a message telling the user that they entered a valid number.

```
if x == False:
    print("wow, you printed a number between 1 and 10!")
```

I answered the stuff for the question, but my problem is that whenever the user enters a wrong number on their first try and a correct number on their second try, the program still considers it as an invalid input. How do I fix this???

Comment: Could you please share your script as one block? Then the community can easily copy and paste to debug.

Comment: You need to update the value of `x` if you input a new number.

Comment: If you only ever assign to `x` once, then it'll only ever have one value. If you want `x` to take a new value, then you should assign to it again. Your teacher wrote four steps to help you program, not because each step corresponds to s distinct "block" of code. The while loop in (c), for instance, will probably encompass (a) and (b)'s code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite this line in the `while` loop:

```py
x = (number > 10 or number < 1)
```

so it becomes

```py
while x == True:
    print("you printed an invalid number")
    number = float(input("please enter the number again, this time between 1 and 10"))
    x = (number > 10 or number < 1)
```

This changes the value of `x` so it doesn't stay at `True`

Comment: do you mean I should paste another one on that part or place it in that part instead?

Comment: Paste another one - otherwise it would say `x is not defined`

Comment: @TheThonnu Code repetition like that makes it difficult to maintain especially when you're hard-coding the range values

Comment: @AlbertWinestein Yes, I know, but I'm just using the brief

Answer (score 1):

If you use a *while True* construct, you won't need to repeat any code. Something like this:

```
LO, HI = 1, 10

while True:
    input_ = input(f'Enter a number between {LO} and {HI}: ')
    try:
        x = float(input_)
        if LO <= x <= HI:
            print(f'Wow! You entered a number between {LO} and {HI}')
            break
        print(f'{input_} is not in range. Try again')
    except ValueError:
        print(f'{input_} is not a valid number. Try again')
```

**Note:**

When asking for numeric input from the user, don't assume that their input can always be converted properly. Always check

Answer (score 0):

The following code snippet should do all you need:

```
number = float(input("Please input a number: "))
while (number > 10 or number < 0):
    number = float(input("Error. Please input a new number: "))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an infinite loop, so that you can prompt for the input only once.

Use `break` to terminate the loop after the number in the correct range is entered.
Use [f-strings or formatted string literals](https://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) to print the message.

```
while True:
    num = float(input('Enter a number between 1 and 10: '))
    if 1 <= num <= 10:
        print('Wow, you printed a number between 1 and 10!')
        break
    else:
        print(f'You printed an invalid number: {num}!')
```

Comment: I don't think this fits the brief - it says you should make a boolean expression and then use that in the `while` loop, not use `while True` and `break`

Comment: @TheThonnu Strictly speaking you are right **but** not all so-called "teachers" know what they're talking about. This is better and more instructive